# Create a passcode screen lock store app

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, keyboard-hook

I want to create a store app always kept on top, forbids users to close it or switch tasks until enter correct passcode. Is it possible to achieve this? f.e. use SetWindowsHookEx like functions to set global keyboard hook to suppress task switch keys, any ideas?

Comment: No, it is a *forbidden* winapi function.  You can't get your app certified if you (somehow) figure out how to call it correctly.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is another mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for responses, I'd like to write a passcode screen lock store app, any ideas?